# Why can't set value of LC_ALL in locale?

Tags: environment-variables, locale

OS in my local pc.

```
uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3 (2019-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My current locale.

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I want to set `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`.

```
sudo localectl set-locale LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
Failed to issue method call: Invalid Locale data.
```

Have a try to set  `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`.

```
sudo localectl set-locale  LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
Failed to issue method call: Invalid Locale data.
```

The default value for `LC_ALL` can only be blank(empty)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in Arch Linux wiki [Locale,LC_ALL: troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale#LC_ALL:_troubleshooting):

> ```
> LC_ALL is the only LC_* variable which cannot be set in locale.conf files: it is meant to be used only for testing or troubleshooting purposes, for example in /etc/profile.
> ```

In [locale.conf — Configuration file for locale settings](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/locale.conf.html), at systemd documentation is stated that:

> ```
> Note that LC_ALL may not be configured in this file.
> ```

Comment: Given the number of answers here — some with upvotes in hundreds — that set LC_ALL carelessly, this answer should be red-lined somehow!